# Java SOAP WebService: how can I use as input an array of String for a method on a WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm developing a WebService SOAP in Java 1.6 version (constraint of infrastruct of customer) and I need to develop an operation method that take as input an plain object with a String and an array of String, and return an output (after some elaboration). The input object it's made of a String *codiceFiscale* and the array of String is that field named *classificazioni* that you see in the code example:

I've this situation on WSDL:

```
<complexType name="VerificaClassiPFInputDTO">
            <sequence>
                <element name="codiceFiscale" nillable="true" type="xsd:string" />
                <element name="classificazioni" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"
                    minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
```

and this is my INPUT DTO (java side):

```
public class VerificaClassiPFInputDTO implements Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = -3933923831884051815L;

/**
 * Codice Fiscale della PF
 */
private String codiceFiscale = "";
/**
 * Array di classificazioni da processare sul codice fiscale passato
 */
private String[] classificazioni = null;

/**
 * Costruttore default
 */
public VerificaClassiPFInputDTO() {
    super();
}

public String getCodiceFiscale() {
    return codiceFiscale;
}

public void setCodiceFiscale(String codiceFiscale) {
    this.codiceFiscale = codiceFiscale;
}

public String[] getClassificazioni() {
    return classificazioni;
}

public void setClassificazioni(String[] classificazioni) {
    this.classificazioni = classificazioni;
}
```

that String[] it's my array. When I deploy the WS, in a SOAPUI client, the situation for this method is this

[image]

and for me is correct. I want "0 on more" String as input in that array, for that field. In this case are three String in the array, and the other string *codiceFiscale*.

Even in IBM RAD Web Service Explorer tool the situation is this:

[image]

so, for me it's ok. But, when I pass more string (in the array) **only the last one been processed**.

[image]

In the code, when I process input, I obtain always **an 1 length array of String**, with the last one.

[image]

So, what's wrong?
**How can I maps that type of input in WSDL, in the DTO etc? Why does this happen?**

If I switct in the DTO the type

```
from String[] to List<String> classificazioni
```

don't work that operation, says mismatch type in the format when run, and I try to call method.

Please someone can help me? If I have to change the map in the WSDL, and the DTO accordingly, that's not a problem but how?

What should I put in the WSDL as *complextype* and consequently in the DTO, in order to have that kind of input?

Please help me....I am going crazy :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think me and my colleagues have solved it. You must write the `setClassificazioni` method in this way:

ADD other two methods

```
public String getClassificazioni(int i){
  return classificazioni[i];
}

public void setClassificazioni(int i, String classificazione){
   this.classificazioni[i] = classificazione;
}
```

IMPORTANT:
It works for arrays of all types, also array having not java primitive type. I don't know if it works also with multidimentional array (adapting method).